# Should range for loop be avoided when possible?

Tags: c++, c++11

In my DirectX program I wrote a loop which iterates through std::string and then I ran performance analyzer and realized that this loop consumes an extreme amount of cpu time. More than that I had about 1300 FPS when I ran my program. So i decided to do something with this and I changed range based loop to typical iterate. I mean i changed:

```
for( char c : std_string_name )
```

to

```
for(size_t i=0; i<std_string_name.size(); ++i )
{ char c = std_string_name[i]; }
```

Now i have about 1900 FPS. 
Isn't it strange?

Next i decided to test the iterator itself, without any loop body. Below I put a link to screenshot with my test results.
str is a long string,
aa, bb, cc are times in clocks.

```
void main(){

    for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
        str += str;

    clock_t a, b, c;
    clock_t aa, bb, cc;

    a=clock();
    iter1(str);
    aa = clock() -a ;

    b=clock();
    iter2(str);
    bb=clock()-b;

    c=clock();
    iter3(str);
    cc=clock()-c;

}

void iter1( std::string str ){
    for( char c : str ){
    }
}

void iter2( std::string str ){
    for( char &c : str ){
    }
}

void iter3( std::string str ){
    for( size_t i=0;i<str.length();++i){
        char c = str[i];
    }
}
```

I get 7017 for `aa`, 6739 for `bb`, 1130 for `cc`.

Why is the for range loop is slow affecting performance so much? What do you think about this? If someone is interested - when i changed passing str by reference instead by value then results are almost the same.

BTW. i use MSVS 2012

Comment: Are you compiling in debug or release mode? Range-based loop uses iterators, and VC++ iterators tend to be slow in debug mode due to additional debug checks; once in release mode, they should boil down to pointers, so there should be no performance difference.

Comment: Don't paste images of code, write the code in the question

Comment: You forgot a variant: `for (const char& c : std_string_name) { ... }`

Comment: MSVS 2012 must have a debugger. Why don't you compare actual disassembly for different cases?

Comment: `main` needs to return `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took your code and wrote this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

int iter1( std::string str ){
    int sum = 0;
    for( char c : str ){
    sum += c;
    }
    return sum;
}

int iter2( std::string str ){
    int sum = 0;
    for( char &c : str ){
    sum += c;
    }
    return sum;
}

int iter3( std::string str ){
    int sum = 0;
    std::string::size_type len = str.length();
    for( size_t i=0;i<len;++i){
        char c = str[i];
    sum += c;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){

    std::string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for(int i=0;i<22;++i)
        str += str;

    clock_t a, b, c;
    clock_t aa, bb, cc;
    int sum = 0;

    a=clock();
    sum += iter1(str);
    aa = clock() -a ;

    b=clock();
    sum += iter2(str);
    bb=clock()-b;

    c=clock();
    sum += iter3(str);
    cc=clock()-c;

    std::cout << "aa=" << aa << " bb=" << bb << " cc=" << cc << " sum=" << sum << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling with `g++ -O2 -Wall -std=c++0x iters.cpp` (gcc 4.6.3) gives the following results:

aa=320000 bb=320000 cc=380000 sum=1048576000

Increasing the optimisation to `-O3` gives a bigger difference:

aa=190000 bb=170000 cc=450000 sum=1048576000

Note that "clock" in Linux isn't very accurate, as it's actually giving CPU time used by the application, which is only updated very 10ms, so I had to make the loops a bit larger.

Quite clearly your assertion is wrong, as the third variant is the SLOWEST in both cases. I can only conclude that you are benchmarking with low or no optimisation.

Comment: It should of course be noted that different compilers may vary, but it is certainly not true that ALL range-based loops are ALWAYS slower than the iterator based ones. And also note that I made sure the loops DOES something (calculate a checksum, in this case), as empty loops can "disappear" if the compiler is clever enough.

Comment: The reason for the third variant being the slowest is that libstdc++'s `std::string` is copy-on-write (which is illegal in C++11, but they keep it for ABI stability), so it has to unshare on every mutable access, like the non-const `operator[]` used here. When they change to a sane implementation, like one similar to the one used in MSVC (non-CoW with SSO), I'd be surprised if there's any meaningful difference between the three.

Answer (score 6):

*(moving from the comments)*

Range-based loop uses iterators, and VC++ iterators tend to be slow in debug mode due to additional debug checks; once in release mode, they should boil down to pointers, so there should be no performance difference.

Also, your test is not meaningful since:

- such empty loops may just be optimized away by the optimizer, so you can run the test reliably only in an unoptimized build - but in an unoptimized build it doesn't make sense so test for performance;
- you are running each test just once and in a particular order - this can give misleading information e.g. due to cache "warming up" in the first loop (although I don't think this is the case, since `str` has just been accessed to be built); to get statistically meaningful information you have to repeat the test many times, in random order.

Comment: May it be that range based loop create end iterator for every iteration when checking condition if std::string has more elements?

Comment: More over, i tested my app in Release mode and now i can't see different at all.

Comment: @MichalW: No, actually one of the main interest of the range-based loop is that it makes sure to cache the `end` iterator; though as a result modifying the iterated-over container within the loop leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that MSVC iterator performance in Debug builds can be considerably improved via the _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL #define.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh697468.aspx